# Cron job to set screen brightness not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, brightness, cron, xbacklight

In the terminal, I ran:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I added the following cronjob in the file

```
26 21 * * * /usr/bin/xbacklight -set 80
```

This was supposed to set the brightness to 80% at 9:26 PM. But its not working. I have tried this command in the terminal directly and it's working. Also, I added another cron job to open cheese at at a particular time and it's working fine. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: which user is running this cronjob? is it the same one which you were using to run it manually?

Comment: yes, the user is same

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying something similar and came across this thread. And I solved it. The problem is that you didn't set the DISPLAY variable first to set the brightness value.

Try:

```
26 21 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xbacklight -set 80
```

You may check the DISPLAY variable on the terminal using:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Happy Croning!

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189629